# What's faster; generating 5 small circles via CSS border-radius; or using a CSS sprite of a small circle repeated 5 times?

Tags: performance, css-sprites, css

All in the title.

I want to do whatever will be fastest.... I would think that 5 CSS generated circles would load faster than having to load an external image, whether its a sprite or not... but I'm looking for somebody who's more educated to offer an opinion!

The circles (to scale, presently generated with CSS):

http://puu.sh/3VZHO.png

Comment: If you are hosted on a fast webhosting, and browsering page with slow PC, use images. On the other way slow webhosting and fast PC, it will be better to use CSS 3.

Comment: The CSS generated circle would be generated faster because of the simple fact that the sprites are downloaded from an external source. The generated circles are created on the processing power of the computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First to answer your question as to which is faster... **The CSS solution is quicker.**  *But why?*

### **The first reason CSS is faster is because of HTTP Requests.**

Every time you have, let's call it an object, that object has to be loaded from the server.  To do this the browser must send an HTTP request to the server for said file, the server has to check if you have permissions to access said file, if you do, it retrieves it's location, and sends it back to the browser.  This happens multiple times and takes hundredths of a second to perform.  Seems pretty quick, but the more of these you have to perform the slower your site will become.

CSS is fastest because the CSS for those 5 circles is contained inside one file style.css

The multi-circle image sprite is slower than CSS because now, not only does the server have to send you style sheet for the rest of the site, it also has to send the your image sprite.  Think of this as ordering a quantity of 2 of the exact same thing from amazon from the same seller.  Amazon will package both items into one big box because its cheaper.  Where ever possible you want to piggy back things like this because it's "cheaper" on load times.

As a further explanation, if you were to load the 5 circles all as separate graphics, 5 individual jpgs/pngs/gifs etc.  This would take EVEN longer because it would have to perform 6 HTTP Request as opposed to 2, or even 1 (the css solution).

### **The second reason CSS is faster is because of shear file-size.**

Let's assume the CSS for your circles has 8 lines of CSS code for each circle, that's 40 total lines.  That represents just bytes of information compared a couple kilo bytes.  To put that better into perspective you are talking 100-400 bytes compared to 4,000-8,000 bytes.

The clear winner?  **CSS**

---

### Other Considerations

That said...  There are other factors which should weight in on your decision.  Not all browsers support border-radius.  See this link for details on what does support border-radius:  [**Can I Use**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius)

Since IE8 and below does not support border-radius anyone using IE8 or earlier will render your circles as boxes instead.  You can help this along by using something like [**Modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/) to fill in some of those gaps.  But now, even if you use a build of Modernizr that helps only border-radius, you've added 7+kb of data and an extra HTTP Request with this file, which sort of defeats your purpose.  That is of course unless there are other things you can use Modernizr for other than border-radius, or if you have a lot more utilizing border-radius than just those 5 circles.  Suddenly the extra data and HTTP request can be easily justified.

Ultimately your decision should be based on your target audience.  What browser are they most likely to be using, if they are mostly using IE9+, Chrome, Firefox etc.  Then go for it.  If a significant number of your visitors are IE8 and below you should consider providing a fallback.  For example using that image sprite for IE8 and below only.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends also in your needs.
I think the border-radius is not rendered correctly in old IE versions, so...maybe the image sprite is the best solution. But I repeat it all depends. Maybe your clients are in a place where internet is slow (css is best) or maybe they won't update their IE and are stuck in IE6 or 7 (sprites).

You could use both, using one stylesheet for IE with sprites and one for css border-radius.

Answer (score 0):

Check the paint times via the chrome dev tools.

Should give you a good idea.

B